# Symlink in Windows 7 fails, although user is an admin

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, symbolic-link

I am logged in Windows 7 (Home Premium) as user which is an administrator. When I open `cmd.exe`, `mklink foo bar` says:

```
You do not have sufficient priviledge to perform this operation.
```

I know I can run `cmd.exe` as administrator (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>), but I would like to create symlinks inside a bigger program (using the win32 API) which will not be running as administrator.

What is the way to enable symlinks for programs running as user (which has administrative privileges), but running the program normally, without explicit elevation?

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be mklink?

I've been using Junction (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) for a long time and it works.

I just tested and it does not need elevated privileges to run. You just need to run once and accept the EULA first. Then you are good to go.

[Edit]

Since you've mentioned in the comments that you are using C++, have you tried it implementing yourself?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Junctions only work with directories AFAIK. I need to create the link programatically, so a code to download does not help.

Comment: It's for a file that you need the link? Sorry. 

You don't need "code to download". You need to install junction.exe once and that's all. 

But I don't think you'll be able to run a command that requires elevated privileges from a program running without elevated privileges. It does not make sense (from a security point of view) to me. 

How will you distribute your program? Which language does it use it?

Comment: It is a mix of python and c++. Why is symlink a security issue under Windows?! Never seen that in Linux.

Comment: Why is creating symlink something for which you  need special permission? Probably because someone considered it dangerous. That's what I meant.